# Is it possible to switch the format of date picker header?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I am trying to change the header on material design date picker as you select a date to a different format than default. Current default is Month , year : ex: june 22, 2021, but I want it such that its Mon, June 22. It's shown on material design document as the first design, but there's no indication of how to go about changing this format?
Any ideas?
[image]

[image]

material designs : https://material.io/components/date-pickers

what I want to achieve is this :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can **NOT** change `Date Format` and `Local` of `MaterialDatePicker`.

Since `MaterialDatePicker` is very restricting, so as many other `Material Design Components`, I recommend you to use an alternate Date Picker Library such as [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker).

It basically fulfills all your needs:

- Change date format: `setLocale(Locale locale)` ✅
- Choose from multiple date UIs ✅
- Very flexiable and easily customizlbe to fit your needs ✅

**PS**: There is one more popular alternative: [android-betterpickers](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers)

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i am a little confused as to why they would add it in their design, when its not achievable? its the first thing that pops up when you open material design doc for date picker : https://material.io/components/date-pickers

Comment: @AngelaHeely Definitely Agree, I am frustrated with Material Components. If you are not willing to use them "AS-IS", then I do not recommend using them at all (even for the future). One story of mine: I had an app that used Material Design Tab bar. The designer suddenly wanted to adjust some margins. But guess what you cannot change its margin values. So I had to recreate Tab Bar from scratch.... If you found this answer helpful, please accept my answer :)

Comment: is there any hack we can do to achieve this?

Comment: @AngelaHeely, sure there is always a hack: you can change the App's locale to achieve your desired behavior. BUT, different Android manufacturers have their own ways of implementing localization. SO, this Hack is not safe and consistent. For example, Samsung and Hwahui treat locale differently.

Comment: As a developer myself, I believe `consistency` is key to success. So I always chose to go the safe way. I mean, there is a reason why libraries such as  `MaterialDateTimePicker.` have 4.7k+ stars...

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the source, and trying some things, I did find a solution. Unfortunately, it's not that simple to implement and I guess switching to  `MaterialDateTimePicker` is still the best solution here.

The conversion from date to text for the header is done by the `DateSelector` via `getSelectionDisplayString(Context context)`. See `getHeaderText()` inside of `MaterialDatePicker` [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/b0558dc006ac60f1c33cff4706bef109a6f77e07/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/MaterialDatePicker.java#L104).

Sadly, `MaterialDatePicker` is final, so you can not simply create your own and override this method. But, with the given Builder, you can use `MaterialDatePicker.Builder.customDatePicker(DateSelector selector)` to place your own DateSelector ([source](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/b0558dc006ac60f1c33cff4706bef109a6f77e07/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/MaterialDatePicker.java#L556)).

Material uses their `SingleDateSelector` ([source](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/SingleDateSelector.java)) for a simple date selection. But again, it's not possible to build upon this selector and write a custom `getSelectionDisplayString` method, because the class is restricted. Knowing this, it's needed to write your own `DateSelector`.

Building your own `DateSelector` is a bigger task on its own. It may be possible to copy from `SingleDateSelector`, but it's using some private classes and methods you need to copy, too.

To cut a long story short, I guess this is too much for "simply" changing the date format.